# Replace column by comparing with the other column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this

```
1      CC     AAA   

1      Na    AAA

1      Na    AAA

1      Na    AAA

1      Na    AAA

1      CC    BBB

1     Na    BBB

1     Na    BBB

1     xa    BBB

1     CC    CCC

1     Na    CCC

1     da    CCC
```

I would like to remove the column 2 and then replce with `"01"` for `AAA`, `"02"` for `BBB` and so on for entire file. Finally the output should looks like,

```
1     01    AAA 

1     01    AAA

1     01    AAA

1     01    AAA

1     01    AAA

1     02    BBB

1     02    BBB

1     02    BBB

1     02    BBB

1     03    CCC

1     03    CCC

1     03    CCC
```

I dont have any clue to make this working. Please help me if possible. Here in every cc the new variable starts. that is from `AAA` to `BBB` can be track by only CC in 2nd column.

Comment: You should at least make an attempt for a solution, and not just ask for one. Maybe this [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) could help you forward. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want:

```
awk '$2=="CC" { a+=1 } {$2=sprintf("%02d",a)} 1' input
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it in `awk`:

```
awk '$3!=a&&NF{a=$3;x=sprintf("%02d",++x);print $1,x,$3;next}$3==a&&NF{print $1,x,$3;next }1' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '$3 != r { ++i } { $2 = sprintf ("%02d", i) } { r = $3 }1' OFS="\t" file
```

I've set the OFS to a tab-char, but you can choose what you like. Results:

```
1   01  AAA
1   01  AAA
1   01  AAA
1   01  AAA
1   01  AAA
1   02  BBB
1   02  BBB
1   02  BBB
1   02  BBB
1   03  CCC
1   03  CCC
1   03  CCC
```